# Problemas con HTTP Put 500 (Internal Server Error) en LARAVEL + VUE

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Cordial saludo.
Tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar unos registro en la base de datos, al parecer los datos son tomados correctamente desde vue.

```
editarCat(item) {
            this.editarcat.Editarid_categoria=item.id_categoria;
            this.editarcat.Editarnombre_categoria=item.nombre_cat;
            console.log(this.editarcat.Editarid_categoria, this.editarcat.Editarnombre_categoria)
        }
```

Este es el código que utilizo para recoger los datos de un array que son recorridos por un V-For y meterlos en los inputs cuando presione el botón con el evento editarCat() para que se puedan editar desde los mismos inputs.

```
editarCategoria(){
             axios.put(`/categorias/${this.editarcat.Editarid_categoria}`, 
              this.editarcat.Editarnombre_categoria)
                .then(res=>{
                 console.log(res.data);
                })
        },
```

Aquí manejo la petición Axios y le paso los parámetros de Id y nombre_categoria

```
Route::resource('/categorias', 'categoriaController');
```

En el archivo web donde establecí las ruta para los distintos métodos HTTP

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $categoria = Categoria::whereRaw('id_categoria = ?', [$id])->get();
        $categoria->nombre_cat = $request->nombre_cat;
        $categoria->save();
        return $categoria;
    }
```

Cabe destacar que para buscar la categoría por un id no me funcionaba con el find() así que busque a ver como me podría funcionar y de esta forma por lo menos me retorna la tupla, también intente hacer el update con Query builder, pero tampoco funciono. Agradecería muchísimo que me pudieran ayudar a encontrar el error.

Tabla de la base de datos:

```
Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_categoria');
            $table->string('nombre_cat');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

//Mensajes de Log

[

```
2020-09-15 20:24:03] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist. {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::save does not exist. at C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Macroable.php:103)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\categoriaController.php(88): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->__call('save', Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\categoriaController->update(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), '1')
#2 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('update', Array)
#4 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(239): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\categoriaController), 'update')
#5 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(196): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(687): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(628): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#25 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(617): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\Users\\Deneros\\Desktop\\IOApp\\IOAppArgon Version 1.4\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\Denero...')
#45 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Hay mensajes de log que puedas agregar?

Comment: Buscare, gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Ya añadí los mensajes

Comment: en la primera linea te está diciendo exactamente lo que tienes que mirar.

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que construyes la actualización no es correcta, prueba así:

- Si usas `get` el resultado de vuelta sería una colección y tendrías que iterar para acceder al objeto deseado
- No hace falta el uso de `whereRaw` pues tenemos métodos como [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) los cuales nos permiten filtrar pasando como argumento el valor de la llave primaria

  - Para este punto estoy asumiendo que `id_categoria` es la llave primaria asociada al modelo `Categoria`
- Aqui [puedes leer mas al respecto sobre actualización](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates)

  ```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
      $categoria = Categoria::findOrFail($id);
      $categoria->nombre_cat = $request->nombre_cat;
      $categoria->save();
      return $categoria;
  }
  ```

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo intente con el findOrFail() y tampoco me sirvió, me sigue dando el mismo 500

Comment: Exactamente el mismo mensaje de error?

Comment: Efectivamente, el mismo error.

Comment: Cuando hago dd dentro del controlador me lanza un mensaje demasiado extenso, tal asi que no puedo pegarlo en la pregunta. No se si lo estaré haciendo mal, apenas inicie con php y vue hace poco

Comment: Trata con un request->all() y revisa si están llegando datos al método, no hace falta lo agregues a tu pregunta, solo revisa si algo llega

Comment: Si le están llegando los datos

Comment: Déjame pensar que más podría ser